# How to copy and paste a div with jQuery's clone() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to clone `container1` but I'm not being successful:

a) This is what I have:

```
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="hello">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="hello">Hello 2</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

b) This is what I expect:

```
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="hello">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="hello">Hello 2</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="hello">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

c) This is what I get:

```
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="hello">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="hello">Hello 2</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 2</div>
  </div>
    <div class="hello">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="goodbye">Goodbye 1</div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
var container1=$('.container1').clone();
$('.container2').after( container1.html() );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FqffM/479/)

Comment: $('.container2').append( $('.container1').clone() );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to call html(). container1 is already a clone. html only returns the inner html.
    
`var container1 = $('.container1').first().clone();
$('.container2').after( container1 );`

should do it.

You could simplify this much further, however I went with the code you already had.

Comment: if it's code is inside a function that's being called (i.e:on click), after cloning and cloning he'll end up with tons of unneeded `.container1`. The following  would help to **get only one**: `$('.container1').first().clone();` ...or using `.last()` ofc.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good idea. I wasn't thinking about reusability.